# parse response time minute wise python

Tags: python, parsing

I have an input file which looks like this and I want to calculate the response times by minutes.

```
datapoint,time,transaction,PT,Responsetime,errorcode
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.873+0000,EditMode,57,109.877193,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.875+0000,Update,58,733.741379,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.875+0000,ViewObject,94,386.893617,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:25.889+0000,EditMode,110,109.209091,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:25.889+0000,Update,109,743.660550,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:25.890+0000,ViewObject,181,376.198895,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:55.904+0000,EditMode,162,109.080247,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:55.904+0000,Update,161,738.683230,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:55.904+0000,ViewObject,266,372.627820,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.918+0000,EditMode,212,108.580189,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.919+0000,Update,213,735.244131,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.919+0000,ViewObject,350,362.394286,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.933+0000,EditMode,263,107.954373,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.933+0000,Update,264,732.598485,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.934+0000,ViewObject,431,359.965197,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.947+0000,EditMode,314,107.815287,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.948+0000,Update,315,733.292063,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.948+0000,ViewObject,516,360.098837,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:55.961+0000,EditMode,368,107.559783,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:55.961+0000,Update,366,731.808743,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:55.962+0000,ViewObject,600,359.780000,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:25.975+0000,EditMode,418,107.406699,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:25.976+0000,Update,419,731.613365,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:25.976+0000,ViewObject,686,358.169096,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:55.989+0000,EditMode,470,107.265957,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:55.990+0000,Update,467,732.107066,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:19:55.990+0000,ViewObject,768,360.317708,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:26.003+0000,EditMode,521,107.149712,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:26.004+0000,Update,521,733.990403,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:26.004+0000,ViewObject,853,361.735053,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:56.018+0000,EditMode,572,107.117133,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:56.018+0000,Update,572,733.139860,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:20:56.018+0000,ViewObject,937,361.497332,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:26.032+0000,EditMode,623,106.855538,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:26.032+0000,Update,623,732.057785,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:26.032+0000,ViewObject,1020,361.191176,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:56.046+0000,EditMode,674,107.112760,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:56.046+0000,Update,674,731.721068,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:21:56.046+0000,ViewObject,1106,360.622966,0
a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:22:26.059+0000,EditMode,724,107.041436,0
```

This is the program I came up with however, this is giving me the entire response time and not for every minute in specific. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

rtlist = []
reqpslist = []

newFile = open('100ulog.csv','r')
FILE = newFile.readlines()
newFile.close()


for line in FILE:
    newline1 = line.split(":")
    newline2 = line.split(",")
    min = newline1[1]
    if newline1[1] == min:
        rtlist.append(newline2[4])
        reqpslist.append(newline2[3])
        print rtlist

    else:
        rtlist[:] = []
        min = min+1
```

Comment: What's your desired output? It's *really* not clear

Comment: Also, you assign `newline1[1]` to `min` and then verify they are equal? What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna go ahead and guess what I think you wanted. If you edit your question I'll edit my answer.
You wanted to get the response times by minutes. Let's first parse the entire file and get the interesting parts -- a) the minute, b) the PT, c) the response time.

We'll use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = open('100ulog.csv','r').read()
>>> lst = re.findall('.+?,.+?T\d+:(\d+):.+?,.+?,(\d+),(\d+\.\d+),', data)
>>> # This will return a list of interesting tuples like: [('16', '181', '376.198895'),...]
```

Now we can do whatever we want with it. Let's say we want to build a dictionary that the minutes are it's keys, and the values are the tuples of the pt and response times (we'll use `collections.defaultdict` for that:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in lst:
...     dic[int(item[0])].append(item[1:3])
```

**EDIT**:

Example:

```
>>> data
'a06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.873+0000,EditMode,57,109.877193,0\na06i0
000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.875+0000,Update,58,733.741379,0\na06i0000003uN
QOAA2,2013-09-26T19:15:55.875+0000,ViewObject,94,386.893617,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA
2,2013-09-26T19:16:25.889+0000,EditMode,110,109.209091,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,201
3-09-26T19:16:25.889+0000,Update,109,743.660550,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26
T19:16:25.890+0000,ViewObject,181,376.198895,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19
:16:55.904+0000,EditMode,162,109.080247,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:5
5.904+0000,Update,161,738.683230,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:16:55.904+0
000,ViewObject,266,372.627820,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.918+0000
,EditMode,212,108.580189,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.919+0000,Upda
te,213,735.244131,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:25.919+0000,ViewObject,
350,362.394286,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.933+0000,EditMode,263,1
07.954373,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.933+0000,Update,264,732.5984
85,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:17:55.934+0000,ViewObject,431,359.965197,
0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.947+0000,EditMode,314,107.815287,0\na0
6i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.948+0000,Update,315,733.292063,0\na06i00000
03uNQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:25.948+0000,ViewObject,516,360.098837,0\na06i0000003u
NQOAA2,2013-09-26T19:18:55.961+0000,EditMode,368,107.559783,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA
2,2013-09-26T19:18:55.961+0000,Update,366,731.808743,0\na06i0000003uNQOAA2,2013-
09-26T19:18:55.962+0000,ViewObject,600,359.780000,0'
>>> import re
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = re.findall('.+?,.+?T\d+:(\d+):.+?,.+?,(\d+),(\d+\.\d+),', data)
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in lst:
...     dic[int(item[0])].append(item[1:3])
...
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {16: [('110', '109.209091'), ('109', '743.660550'), (
'181', '376.198895'), ('162', '109.080247'), ('161', '738.683230'), ('266', '372
.627820')], 17: [('212', '108.580189'), ('213', '735.244131'), ('350', '362.3942
86'), ('263', '107.954373'), ('264', '732.598485'), ('431', '359.965197')], 18:
[('314', '107.815287'), ('315', '733.292063'), ('516', '360.098837'), ('368', '1
07.559783'), ('366', '731.808743'), ('600', '359.780000')], 15: [('57', '109.877
193'), ('58', '733.741379'), ('94', '386.893617')]})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted the response times of all transactions that occured during a minute. For ex. during 19:15:55, there are 3 transactions and I want to collect the response times of these in a list. After which i need to collect response times for 19:16:55. Sorry about not being clear.

Comment: Well my answer should give you that, in a scope of the "minute". Meaning all the transactions that occurred in 19:**16**, then all that happened in 19:**17** etc.. `dic` will hold them. Try it

Comment: Sorry, had a typo and added an example. Check it out.